# Proving that cosine is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

This is what I've already done. Can't think of how to proceed further

$$|\cos(x)-\cos(y)|=\left|-2\sin\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)\right|\leq\left|\frac{x+y}{2}\right||x-y|$$

What should I do next?

Comment: Use that $|\sin(x)| \leq 1$.

Comment: So, instead of writing $\frac{|x+y|}{2}|x-y|$ I could've written
$\leq |-2*1*\frac{x-y}{2}|=|x-y|$ and then I can just set delta equal to epsilon?

Comment: @user1242967 Only drop the $|x+y|/2$ part.  Turn that into an answer to your own question and you have my upvote.  You have shown it in the best way yet.

Comment: @DavidMitra I think you have to be slightly more involved than that, $|x-y| < \delta$ for $\delta < 4\pi$ doesn't necessarily mean that we can we can "shift" both $x$ and $y$ to be in $[-2\pi, 2\pi]$. I may be missing something, but I think you have to be slightly more fiddly, as in my hint below.

Comment: @TomOldfield You'd of course demand that $\delta$ be less than $\min\{1,\delta_\epsilon\}$, say. I think this would work... Regardless, I deleted my comment as the OP's solution together with WimC's hint provides the best solution, in my opinion.

Comment: @DavidMitra You're right, I think that works, thank you! I agree with you about their solution being better, I just wrote down the first thing that came to mind!

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Any continuous function is uniformly continuous on a closed, bounded interval, so $\cos$ is uniformly continuous on $[-2\pi,0]$ and $[0,2\pi]$.

Answer (score 2):

The cosine function is Lipschitz-continuous because its derivative is bounded.  That follows from the mean value theorem.  Every Lipschitz-continuous function is uniformly continuous.

**postscript prompted by Tom Oldfield's comment:** A function $f$ is Lipschitz-continuous iff there is some non-negative number $m$ such that for all $x,y$ in the domain of $f$ we have $|f(x)-f(y)|\le m|x-y|$.  This is stronger than uniform continuity, in that every Lipschitz-continuous function is uniformly continuous, but not every uniformly continuous function is Lipschitz continuous.  An example of a uniformly continuous function that is not Lipschitz-continuous is $x\mapsto\sqrt{1-x^2}$ on the interval $[-1,1]$.  It's really easy to prove that Lipschitz continuity entails uniform continuity.

Comment: You can prove that it's uniformly continuous without mentioning Lipschitz continuity using exactly the same proof, in case people haven't heard of, or don't use much, Lipschitz continuity.